# How to deal with race conditions in multi-threading?

Tags: c#, multithreading, race-condition

Here's an example:

```
if (control.InvokeRequired)
{
    control.BeginInvoke(action, control);
}
else
{
    action(control);
}
```

What if between the condition and the BeginInvoke call the control is disposed, for example?

Another example having to do with events:

```
var handler = MyEvent;

if (handler != null)
{
    handler.BeginInvoke(null, EventArgs.Empty, null, null);
}
```

If `MyEvent` is unsubscribed between the first line and the if statement, the if statement will still be executed. However, is that proper design? What if with the unsubscription also comes the destruction of state necessary for the proper invocation of the event? Not only does this solution have more lines of code (boilerplate), but it's not as intuitive and can lead to unexpected results on the client's end.

What say you, SO?

Comment: the reason the pattern described above for event handlers exists is to keep a reference to the handler alive so it can't be disposed.

Comment: @Mitch Wheat: Yes I'm not saying the handler is necessarily disposed but that if the client unsubscribes from the event he or she may also decide they no longer need some sort of state object that is normally only used by the event handler. Because the event still runs after unsubscribed with unfortunate timing, there may be a very hard to trace error because the expected result was that the handler would not run after unsubscribed.

Comment: @Mitch Wheat: Maybe I'm not understanding this properly. Assuming the application was multi-threaded and a client unsubscribed from the event in between the first line and the if statement, would not the event still run?

Comment: You may want to read [Eric Lippert's article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/29/events-and-races.aspx) on why this possibility exists with events and why it's the caller's responsibility to ensure that they _don't_ wipe state or handle state failures appropriately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my opinion, if any of this is an issue, both your thread management and object lifecycle management are reckless and need to be reexamined.

In the first example, the code is not symmetric: `BeginInvoke` will not wait for `action` to complete, but the direct call will; this is probably a bug already.

If you expect yet another thread to potentially dispose the control you're working with, you've no choice but to catch the `ObjectDisposedException` -- and it may not be thrown until you're already inside `action`, and possibly not on the current thread thanks to `BeginInvoke`.

It is improper to assume that once you have unsubscribed from an event you will no longer receive notifications on it.  It doesn't even require multiple threads for this to happen -- only multiple subscribers.  If the first subscriber does something while processing a notification that causes the second subscriber to unsubscribe, the notification currently "in flight" will still go to the second subscriber.  You may be able to mitigate this with a guard clause at the top of your event handler routine, but you can't stop it from happening.

Comment: I'd be looking carefully at code that allowed one subscriber to cause an event that unsubscribes a second subcriber to the same event

Answer (score 3):

There are a few techniques for resolving a race condition:

- Wrap the whole thing with a mutex.  Make sure that there's a lock that each thread must first acquire before it can even start running in the race.  That way, as soon as you get the lock, you know that no other thread is using that resource and you can complete safely.
- Find a way to detect and recover from them;  This can be very tricky, but some kinds of application work well;  A typical way of dealing with this is to keep a counter of the number of times a resource has changed;  If you get finished with a task and find that the version number is different from when you started, read the new version and start the task over from the beginning (or just fail)
- redesign the application to use only atomic actions;  basically this means using operations that can be completed in one step;  this often involves "compare-and-swap" operations, or fitting all of the transaction's data into a single disk block that can be written atomically.
- redesign the application to use lock-free techniques;  This option only makes sense when satisfying hard, real-time constrains is more important than servicing every request, because lock-free designs inherently lose data (usually  of some low priority nature).

Which option is "right" depends on the application.  Each option has performance trade-offs that may make the benefit of concurrency less appealing.

Answer (score -1):

If this behavior is spreading multiple places in your application, it might deserve to re-design the API, which looks like:

```
if(!control.invokeIfRequired()){
    action(action);
}
```

Just the same idea as standard JDK library `ConcurrentHashMap.putIfAbsent(...)`. Of course, you need to deal with synchronization inside this new `control.invokeIfRequired()` method.

Comment: The 2nd example is pretty interesting, as it's possible that `handler` can be assigned null by other threads. We need a lock object here, so each read and write to `handler` is guarded by the same lock. I'm not sure about C#. But in Java, the working code might looks like: `synchronized(lockObj){if(handler!=null){handler.beginInvoke(...)}}`

Comment: -1 This suggestion, while useful, is _not_ an answer to the question.